# How to set input type range to default value on changing the min and max value dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function rangeSlider(){
    if(toShowBet == true){
        $("#rangeInput").attr({
          "min": minAmount,
          "max": maxAmount,
          "value": maxAmount,
        });
    }
    document.getElementById("rangevalue").value = maxAmount;  
}
```

```html
<div class="buyInLabel"><span id="raiseAndBetText">Raise:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<output id="rangevalue"></output></div>
<div class="rangeSliderSetUp">
  <input type="range" min="" max="" value="" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value" oninput="rangevalue.value=value" style="margin-top: 4%;" id="rangeInput">
</div>
```

I have query related to set the thumb of range slider to default value(max value) every time on dynamically changing in "min" and "max" value of range slider.
Actually I am using same slider all time, but every time when i call the dynamic value of min and max. The thumb of slider not set to max value but the output value display the max value of slider.
Please help me to solve this query. Thank you

Comment: can show your code please?

Comment: The problem is in your code. :)

Comment: I think, I want a logic to initialize the slider on dynamic changes in min and max value. In this way the thumb will be reset every time. But i don't know how i can initialize or reset the slider on every call